# Does sqlalchemy have a filter object like Q in django?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How to rewrite this code which used django orm on sqlalchemy orm?

```
list_of_filters = [Q(active=True)]

if self.proxy_anonymity:
    list_of_filters.append(Q(anonymity=True))

if self.proxy_https:
    list_of_filters.append(Q(https=True))

if hasattr(spider, 'bad_proxies') and spider.bad_proxies:
    list_of_filters.append(~Q(ip__in=spider.bad_proxies))

proxy_filter = reduce(operator.and_, list_of_filters)

return proxy_filter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLAlchemy uses a different approach by providing instrumented attributes on mapped classes, as explained in ["Declare a Mapping"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#declare-a-mapping):

> When our class is constructed, Declarative replaces all the [`Column`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column) objects with special Python accessors known as [descriptors](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/glossary.html#term-descriptors); this is a process known as [instrumentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/glossary.html#term-instrumentation).

You can then use those attributes to form predicate expressions etc. using what is called the [SQL Expression Language](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html).

There are some similarities when forming the actual expressions, such as using the bitwise operators `|`, `&`, and `~` as OR, AND, and NOT respectively. Alternatively SQLAlchemy provides the constructs [`or_()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.or_), [`and_()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.and_), and [`not_()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.not_). All in all you should read ["Querying"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#querying) in the ORM tutorial.

So if your model class was for example `Proxy`, your code could look like

```
# Note that it is redundant to compare a boolean column with a boolean value.
# Just use the value of the column itself.
list_of_filters = [Proxy.active]

if self.proxy_anonymity:
    # Again, use a boolean column as is.
    list_of_filters.append(Proxy.anonymity)

if self.proxy_https:
    list_of_filters.append(Proxy.https)

if hasattr(spider, 'bad_proxies') and spider.bad_proxies:
    list_of_filters.append(Proxy.ip.in_(spider.bad_proxies))

proxy_filter = and_(*list_of_filters)

return proxy_filter
```